# Magento 2 emails stop working suddenly

Tags: magento-2.1, order-email

I have a store in Magento 2.1.7. My emails were working fine a few days ago but suddenly it stops working. I also noticed my config fields in the admin panel are also not editable anymore and I'm not able to change copyright text as well. I don't know what happened. I tried to clear magento cache but no success.

Comment: What do you mean by `stop working`? Did you check you logs in `var/log/*`?

Comment: This is what i found under update log file:  update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/nginx.conf.sample  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/.travis.yml  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/.php_cs  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/Gruntfile.js.sample  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/package.json.sample  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/php.ini.sample  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/.htaccess.sample  /chroot/home/atzeninf/atzen.info/html/.user.ini [] []

Answer (score 0):

I checked the database and found cron jobs are being scheduled but not executing. How to fix this issue?

[image: Screenshot from phpmyadmin]

Comment: There seems to be an issue with your Magento crons - check the [docs for setting up a Magento cron](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html). Unfortunately I cannot find any docs for Magento 2.1 - the most recent versions are 2.3, 2.4